# Videoportal PWA (Progressive Web App) Video offline function?

Tags: android, google-chrome, video, offline, progressive-web-apps

We want to build a Videoportal as a PWA. Every video will have a watch offline feature. Can this be done via the Serviceworker caching?  Or should another Download-Mechanism enable this Feature. The videos size is about 120mb. Target Device is Android and Web.(Sorry for bad english)

Comment: See https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sample-media-pwa

Comment: Do you get any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the Cache Storage API along with service workers to handle offline video playback.

There's a complete sample app at https://github.com/googlearchive/sample-media-pwa.

If you were to use the Workbox libraries for handling your caching logic, then [this guidance should help](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#cached-av). If you don't end up using Workbox, then you'll need to implement some logic to handle `Range:` requests in your service worker, or else your video playback will likely not behave as expected when the `<video>` element tries to load a partial chunk of video bytes.