# How to offline video content using PWA?

Tags: offline, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have few questions on PWA offline videos.

- How can I offline the video using the Progressive Web App?
- Which storage mechanism should I use to store video data on the client side?
- Is there any storage limit browser-wise?

I did offline functionality with text data using PWA using service workers. But stuck in how to do same with video.

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: Try following this [sample app by chrome](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sample-media-pwa), it was also given in a similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44303314/videoportal-pwa-progressive-web-app-video-offline-function#comment75756221_44303314). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

this is helpful repository

PWA download video manager use local database PouchDB

you can download video and store video Blob data in local Database and Use that offline

https://github.com/mohammadnazari110/pwa_offline_video_download

Comment: I think this is the right approach. I personally use localforage for IndexedDB interactions, but any IDB library that works for you run with it.
This approach is particularly helpful due to Apple's limited service worker cache quota. 
They are not as restrictive with IDB, which you can store GBs of data :)